# What is the I/O strategy of the following several web server?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, webserver, tornado

There are five basic I/O model:

- blocking IO
- nonblocking IO
- IO multiplexing
- signal driven IO
- asynchronous IO

I'm wondering which one is used in nodejs and tornado?(maybe 3rd or 4th?)

And is there a web server that uses the real async IO( 5th, using aio_xxx lib) ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, NodeJs uses I/O multiplexing for network I/O and a blocking I/O with a thread pool for disk I/O.

**Here goes the long answer:**

Nodejs uses a library called libuv for all I/O. libuv, as you can see in the diagram below (taken from http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html), internally uses the system calls `epoll` (in Linux), `kqueue` (in Free BSD), event ports (in Solaris) and IOCP (in Windows).

These system calls are basically I/O multiplexing (network I/O, not disk I/O). The key idea here is:

1. The application thread registers the file descriptors it is interested in with the kernel
2. The kernel maintains these data in its own internal data structures. It also maintains a list of all application threads to wake up against each file descriptor. This allows the kernel to wake up the threads efficiently when the file descriptor (socket) becomes ready for read (socket buffer is full with data) or write (buffer is empty for writing data)
3. The kernel also does other optimizations such as coalescing multiple events of a single file descriptor

This idea mainly originated in a [paper by Banga et al](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix99/full_papers/banga/banga.pdf) which inspired the development `kqueue` and `epoll`.

Even before these system calls were available, I/O multiplexing existed in the form of system calls `select` and `poll` which did not scale well. `select` and `poll` mainly required the application thread to submit the list of file descriptors they are interested in with every call. The kernel is stateless for these system calls. This resulted in multiple scans of the list by both kernel and the application causing scalability issues.

Now as for the asynchronous I/O, I think it mainly refers to the POSIX AIO specification. Given the way network I/O are handled by I/O multiplexing, the POSIX specification could be useful for disk I/O only. However, libuv doesn't use it and probably this is not is use by any webserver mainly because of poor implementations, not all disk operations could be asynchronous etc. The detailed list of reasons it is not used by libuv are mentioned [here](https://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/10/asynchronous-disk-io/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nonblocking I/O used in nodejs, tornado used asynchronous & nonoblocking model because one operation can active at the same time. 
Also NGINX server uses an async.